# Why does my implementation of the Great Circle distance formula give wrong results?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, distance, great-circle

I'm trying to implement algorithm which will calculate distance between 2 points using great circle distance formula according to [guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/great-circle-distance-formula/)

My function:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians


def get_great_circle_distance(first_coords, second_coords, radius):
    """
    :param first_coords: (first_client_latitude, first_client_longitude) <- degrees
    :param second_coords: (second_client_latitude, second_client_longitude) <- degrees
    :param radius: planet radius
    :return: distance
    """

    la_1, lo_1 = map(radians, first_coords)
    la_2, lo_2 = map(radians, second_coords)

    denominator = cos(
        cos(la_1) * cos(la_2) * cos(lo_1 - lo_2) +
        sin(la_1) * sin(la_2)
    )
    distance = radius / denominator

    return distance
```

For example I call:
`distance = get_great_circle_distance((55, 28), (86, 70), 7)` and expecting `~3.93km`, but I get 10.56897.

Comment: If not a typo, this seems like really a math question. I agree that the notation makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked formula uses cos<sup>-1</sup> which means the inverse of the cosine function. cos<sup>-1</sup>(x) is not the same as 1/cos(x).

It is also known as [arccos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions). In Python it is called [acos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.acos).